# Referencing variables in Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

To differentiate between different app flavors, I want to make a reference to the `applicationId` in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags += '-DAPPLICATION_ID="' + applicationId + '"'
    }
}
```

But gradle tells me that it

**Could not get unknown property 'applicationId' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.**

How could I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36041577/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare It works with the stringize macro trick. I find no way to put a string like -DAPP_ID="..." since the quotes are all eaten away even when I put -DAPP_ID=\"...\".